# Method not found: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.BaseConnectionContext.get_Features()

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I have an ASP.NET Core 5.0 Web API used with an angular Web client. I'm using SignalR and it works fine.

Now I want to use a SignalR client to communicate with a third party service. So I installed the Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client nuget.

As soon as I start the Web API, and even without instanciating a SignalR client, I have the following error:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.IFeatureCollection Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.BaseConnectionContext.get_Features()'.

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.HttpConnectionContext..ctor(String connectionId, String connectionToken, ILogger logger)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.HttpConnectionManager.CreateConnection(PipeOptions transportPipeOptions, PipeOptions appPipeOptions, Int32 negotiateVersion)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.HttpConnectionDispatcher.CreateConnection(HttpConnectionDispatcherOptions options, Int32 clientProtocolVersion)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.HttpConnectionDispatcher.ProcessNegotiate(HttpContext context, HttpConnectionDispatcherOptions options, ConnectionLogScope logScope)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.HttpConnectionDispatcher.ExecuteNegotiateAsync(HttpContext context, HttpConnectionDispatcherOptions options)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I understand the error message, but not why adding a NuGet replaced a core server component. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry but can I ask how you integrate Signalr into your api project? Follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)?

Comment: I installed the nuget.

Comment: yes sir, I created a new web api project and installed the nuget package and it certainly worked, so I just want to ask how you composed your project or which tutorial you followed so that we may try to reproduce your issue...

Comment: The web api project was created about 3 years ago, probably ASP.NET Core 2.2

Comment: I try to add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` unget package to a .net core 2.1 project but failed, maybe your issue came from the compatibility？

Answer (score 0):

The fix in my case was I had to update all .NET libraries from **5.0.12** to the latest **5.0.15**.